# chart js - Apply different color for each x-axes label

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I have a chart built using Chart Js. Need to apply different color for each label rather than applying same color for all labels. Is there a way to do it in ticks call back function. ?

```
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{ 
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
            callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                  if ('Feb 9, 2016' === label) {
                  fontColor: "red"; // Something like this
                   return label+'f';
                } else {
                    return label;
                }
                },
             // fontColor: "red", // this here
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
            },
        }],
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442), you can't currently do it without changing `Chart.js` source code (easy fix though)